# Monitor program/process execution in windows using java

Tags: java

I am trying to develop a small application that can monitor the programs/processes that are executing in a windows machine.

If the program/process is not supposed to run, it should be blocked. It works similar to an antivirus.

This is the basic idea.

I want to know the ways to hook into the OS to get notified about every single program/process trying to run in the machine.

And i want it in java... any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Java wouldn't be your best answer sorry mate.  It's not limited to the JVM, can get access outside of that, but for what you're looking for, it wouldn't be an efficient language to use unfortunately.  By all means see what other answers you get though.